# how to access host behind a bastion?

Tags: proxy, bastion

I have bunch of hosts that can be accessed only from bastion hosts ( A linux server where I can ssh into and access my real host ).

Iam able to access it using firefox with socks proxy, now How can I do the same on command line ?

so all my comandline programs and protocols such as ping, SNMP, RMCP/IPMI all work seamlessly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to indicate that your bastion host is a SSH server and although the SSH protocol allows you to use SSH to tunnel other traffic it is far from ideal.

A much better solution would be to (additionally/instead) run a VPN server on the bastion host.

Answer (score 0):

Check out something like [Socksify](https://www.inet.no/dante/doc/1.3.x/socksify.1.html).

There are also some other command line utilities that will proxy all connections to a socks proxy.

Comment: Or `tsocks`: http://tsocks.sourceforge.net/